# Does this scenario equate to any well known computer science problems?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, combinations

I'm working on a problem in the field of survey data integration, but it's easier to describe with an artificial analogy. Since the setup is a bit lengthy I'll pose my questions at the outset:

1. Does this scenario equate to any computer science problems whose solutions I could simply borrow and adapt?
2. If not, what approaches might you suggest? I'm not asking anyone to solve the problem; rather, just hoping to be pointed in one or more promising directions.

Imagine that **ecosystems** have **creatures**, which consist of one or more **molecules**, which consist of one or more **atoms**. To be viable creature, its molecules must collectively use exactly one of each type of atom. In the example below, note that every creature uses all four atoms just once. Also worth noting is that the ordering of molecules within creatures and of atoms within molecules is irrelevant.

```
Atoms in the universe: a b c d.

Ecosystem X
    creature x1
        molecule 1: a b
        molecule 2: c
        molecule 3: d
    creature x2
        molecule 4: a b c
        molecule 5: d
    creature x3
        molecule 6: a b c d

Ecosystem Y
    creature y4
        molecule 7: a b
        molecule 8: c
        molecule 9: d
    creature y5
        molecule 10: a b
        molecule 11: c d
```

Given two ecosystems, my task is to produce "pairings". A pairing consists of a set of molecules (or molecule combinations) from one ecosystem that map to equivalent molecules (or molecule combinations) from the other ecosystem. Equivalence is determined by the underlying atoms. Like creatures, pairings are not viable unless each of the two sets of molecules (one from each ecosystem) uses all of the atoms exactly once. Here are some (not all) of the pairings from the example above:

```
# A direct mapping from the molecules of creature x1 to those of y4.
m1 = m7
m2 = m8
m3 = m9

# As above, but substitute m10 for m7.
m1 = m10
m2 = m8
m3 = m9

# We can combine molecules.
m4 = m7 + m8
m5 = m9

# Another combination.
m1      = m10
m2 + m3 = m11
```

In the real problem domain, there could anywhere from 2 to 100 atoms in play (with corresponding variety in molecule sizes) and a couple dozen creatures per ecosystem. Also, it's possible for two ecosystems to produce no viable pairings. In that case, my Python application will eventually need to suggest approximate pairings (a list of the molecule combinations that pair up, followed by a listing of the stragglers from each ecosystem).

Comment: You want to find *all* the possible pairings given two ecosystems?

Comment: Well, I strongly want to see a mathematical aspect. Your creatures are  **partitions** of your set of molecules. Each molecule is thus a **subset** What you may do is code your partitions in any way you want, then use hastables. You may also want to "add" several subsets, to form bigger subsets, and insert them also in the hashtable (for the `m2 + m3 = m11` case). Then, check for collisions. I have no idea how to bring approximate pairings

Comment: How do the creatures affect pairings? In my reading of the problem statement, it seems that since pairings happen at the molecule level, the creature-level groupings of molecules don't seem relevant to pairings.

Comment: @mhum Correct: creatures do not affect pairings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This smells like some flavor of [covering problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

1. Index (hash) molecules by their atom subsets, producing mappings like `{a, b} -> {m1, m7, m10}`
2. Select an ecosystem and, by enumerating partitions, discover and index atom subsets with their other-ecosystem expansions (such as `{a, b, c} -> {{{a, b}, {c}}}` for `m4 = m7 + m8`.)
3. Discard any atom subsets that don't have an expansion (understanding that `m1 = m7` counts as an expansion.)
4. From the remainder, enumerate partitions of the alphabet (set of all atoms.)  From step 3, we know that any discovered partitions will be translatable into potentially many partitions in the other ecosystem, via the mapping already computed.
5. Select the other ecosystem and repeat steps 2-4.
6. De-dupe results (possibly by accumulating them in a hash set.)
7. Expand partitions composed of subsets of atoms back into collections of molecules with the mapping built in step 1.

The one part that seems tricky off-hand is the sub-routine that accepts a collection of subsets and enumerates the constructible partitions of some target set.  Depending on the exact semantics, that may in fact be NP-hard.

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestions. I'm think I'm dealing with the **exact cover problem** -- two of them, in fact. Using the terminology of this Wikipedia example (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover#Detailed_example), `X` corresponds to my "atoms in the universe", `S` corresponds to the "molecules in one ecosystem", and `A-F` correspond to "molecules". For each ecosystem, I need to find all of the exact covers. Then I need to determine whether any pairs of exact covers (taking an exact cover from each ecosystem) align perfectly. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: With the added twist that "alignment" takes into account this notion of detected rule-based expansion, yes.